# AS/400: Why would DB2 table changes not immediately take effect throughout entire system?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I've got an issue where I updated a table in our AS/400 - db2 on the backend but the changes are not reflected through the front end.

We have a table called "SH.PROM" which is to specify our monthly promotions' date ranges. I have updated "SH.PROM" with the proper packed & zoned decimals and EBCDIC characters. However, when other people try to enter in the item #s of discounted items, the discounts aren't showing on the front end.

Is there a command to invoke a system wide update so that changes take effect immediately?

Comment: If `SH.PROM` is loaded into `QTEMP` (for example when the user(s) sign on) then they will still hold the old information rather than your updated information. If this is the case, simply having them sign off and then back on will update their local copies.

Comment: Is there anything that will help me tell whether SH.PROM's current version is being used? Here's the DSPFD: http://i.imgur.com/xswA5V8.jpg & http://i.imgur.com/wBjkC2w.jpg

Comment: If your table is under commitment control, have the changes been committed?

Comment: Are the users able to find other promotions?  Is there more than one of these files on the system? (Use `WRKOBJ *ALL/SH.PROM`) If so look at their job(s) with WRKJOB option 14 to see open files which will tell you which library the job opened that file in.

Comment: You can do a `WRKOBJLCK <library_name>/SH.PROM *FILE` to see what jobs/users have a lock on the file at any given time. That won't tell you who has touched it in the past, only who is using it **right this second**. WarrenT's suggestion to look at a user's job and see which files are open is a helpful - you'll be able to see if the user is using the `SH.PROM` you modified or a different one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that you are updating the table with an RPG program.
Let's further assume that the RPG program declares SH.PROM as an update primary file without keys.
In this case, RPG (for the sake of efficiency) will buffer the database operations, storing the updated rows in an internal buffer until the program ends and the buffer is flushed to disk.  If this is the case, there will be a message at the bottom of the RPG compiler listing to the effect that blocking is being used.  Under this circumstance, it is possible that a table can be updated by one program but the updated row is not yet known to the database.

There is a slightly different scenario if you are operating under commitment control, but if we assume that a row is locked for update and not yet COMMITted then other jobs will hold on that lock.  Instead of seeing the old data, they won't be able to read the uncommitted change at all and will instead eventually get a record wait timeout.

There is another scenario where you have a logical file built over SH.PROM which is MAINT(*REBLD).  You update SH.PROM; the end users read through SH.PROML1 and it takes some time to rebuild the index before they can see the records.

Aside from that, there really isn't a way to delay or defer database updates.  Generally speaking, if you update a row, it's immediately available.  None of the above scenarios seem to reflect what you are reporting.  Check to make sure that you are updating the same table that the users are accessing.  It is possible that you are updating TESTLIB/SH.PROM and the users are reading PRODLIB/SH.PROM.  Or, there might be some nightly process which propagates SH.PROM into other tables, and it is these tables which the end users access.

The bit about 'proper packed & zoned decimals and EBCDIC characters' is confusing.  How are you updating SH.PROM?  JDBC?  RPG?  SQL statement run via IBM i Navigator?  Why is it interesting to note 'proper packed & zoned decimals'?  Is it because SH.PROM is a flat file (no actual columns defined) and you've had to emulate packed decimal fields via use of SQL built in functions?

Comment: How about an output file. Records could also be buffered until closed or the force ratio met.

Comment: If the other jobs already have the file open as a logical with delayed maintenance, then the the index might not be updated until someone opens it again.

Comment: (As soon as you say "there's no other way" you leave yourself open to somebody suggesting another way ;)

Comment: I noted both of those scenarios in my answer.  They don't seem to fit the question as asked - OP uses the word 'updated' several times.

Comment: I have accepted Buck's answer. Yesterday was a horrible case of the Mondays. Being on the admin side of a system older than me I made a horrible rookie error and panicked. I kept trying to verify that the promos were correct through our order/invoice application and incidentally used a customer number not enabled to view promos. I noted 'properly packed/zoned decimals and EBCDIC characters' to emphasize it was not a data error. I knew it was something external to the database. While that external component was ME I considered other parts of the system. I used an ODBC connection w/ SQL.

Comment: There is much to the AS/400 I do not know as I am still learning. A long term goal of mine is to migrate this system elsewhere but I must have command and control here first. Thank you all for the insight. I have duly noted each one of your comments.

Comment: The Apple Macintosh is 5 years older than the AS/400.  There's no reason to panic just because a computing platform has a long history.  Don't assume that IBM i is totally alien.  There ARE IBM-specific processes, but the general principles of business computing are the same whether implemented in DB2 for i or SQL Server or MySQL.

Comment: I should have specified migrating to a more modern IBM system so not entirely elsewhere.  I believe IBM i is here to stay with this particular company. The AS/400 was clearly a system built to last and has functioned here for quite some time. We have a power 7 that I'd like to eventually have our website running from in addition to an upgraded system. http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/6886/aw9r.jpg